# Why is this form not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a mailer so that I have a business directory, each business listing has a form and when the form is filled out and submitted it is sent to the relative business email with the lead information.

Here's the mailer folder file:

```
class Enquiry < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "admin@uk-franchise.co.uk"
  attr_accessible :name

  def lead(listing)
    @listing = listing
    mail(to: @listing.leadrecepient, subject: "test")
  end
end
```

Here's the listing controller where I'm calling it:

```
  def lead
  listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  Enquiry.lead(listing).deliver
  redirect_to listing
  end
```

The view:

```
  <%= form_for @listing, url: lead_listing_path(@listing), method: :put do |listing| %>
    <%= listing.text_field :name %>
    <%= listing.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

The routes:

```
  resources :listings do
    member do
      put :lead
    end
  end
```

And the error :(

```
undefined method `name' for #<Listing:0x4d7c6d8>
```

On the view line:

```
<%= listing.text_field :name %>
```

Any help greatly appreciated, mailers are a nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `form_for` helper, it actually rely on a model object. Doing this, when you write `listing.text_field :name` it will actually look for a field `name` in the `listing` model. You get that error because your model (connected to a DB table? we would like to see the `listing` class) doesn't have this field. I can see it in the Enquiry class.
I would say you have to move it in the model, but is hard to say without seeing the Model or knowing for what you need that field...
Show us the model and explain a little better what are you trying to do, so we can help you  :)